# How I can keep a variable session in JSF?

Tags: session, jsf

I have the following code:

```
    if (httpServletR.getSession().getAttribute("ush_id") != null) {
    rol_id = Integer.parseInt(httpServletR.getSession().getAttribute("rol_id").toString());
    logger.info("Rol: "+rol_id);
    Rol rl=new Rol();
    rl.setRol_id(rol_id);
}
```

Where basically if the user exists the role is set, but when I try to recover the role from the bean:

> ```
> public void selectmtvlista() throws Exception {
>     motivosolicitudDAO dao = new motivosolicitudDAO();
>     adminBean adm = new adminBean();
>     int rolid = adm.getRol_id();
>     try {
>         this.selectmotivosolicitud = dao.listarSelectMotivoSolicitud(rolid);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         throw e;
>     }
> }
> ```

I do not recover the role defined in the first piece of code. and given that selectmtvlista () should return the list of options for the role, I return something else. So it would be best to keep rol_id in a session variable, but as establesco this variable and how they recovered from the Bean?

Any help, I am grateful.

Comment: Just make it a property of a session scoped managed bean? You can in turn inject/access that bean from anywhere in webapp.

Comment: How can I do that?